# How to make Windows go to sleep from app?

Tags: c++, delphi, windows-7, sleep, windows-messages

Im trying to make an app that can put windows 7 to sleep, 
I have been looking at WM_Messages, but cant seem to find one that does the jobb.

I can use ether C++ or Delphi to make the app if there it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function which is in **powrprof.dll**:

```
function SetSuspendState(hibernate, forcecritical, disablewakeevent: boolean): boolean;
    stdcall; external 'powrprof.dll' name 'SetSuspendState';

SetSuspendState(false, false, false); // stand by
SetSuspendState(true, false, false); // hibernate
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373233%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN page will help.